# The system cannot find the file specified ( Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor )

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have recently downgraded an application using .net 4.5.1 to 4.0, after installing the app and running I get the following error!

Surprisingly the same app works on my local machine but it wont run on test machine. My local machine has .net 4.5.1 installed, test machine has same .net version installed.

Currently I have a Controller (A) which inherits from a basecontroller and this base controller does have a parameterless public constructor with some mapping going on there.

> **The system cannot find the file specified**
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6568558
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +6595000
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +219
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6597350
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6597891
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +942
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +6601145
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +103
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2102
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1079
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6605639
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +207
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +438
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32() +582
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +15
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +263
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +749
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +314
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +326
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +230
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +129
>      System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +267
>      System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +217
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +66
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +596
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +208
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +263
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +72
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +64
>      System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +85
>      OnlinePolicySales.Operations.CacheManager.get_Translations() +440
>      OnlinePolicySales.Operations.Extensions.LocalizationExtensions.Translate(String IdString, String[] args) +49
>      OnlinePolicySales.Web.Attributes.RequiredIfAttribute..ctor(String otherProperty, Comparison comparison, Object value, String modelPrefix) +260
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs) +0
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs) +77
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +1294
>      System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimePropertyInfo property, RuntimeType caType) +149
>      AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateMappingExpression(TypeMap typeMap, Type destinationType) +253
>      AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, MemberList memberList) +27
>      OnlinePolicySales.Web.Helpers.MapperHelper.MapModelsToViewModels() +247
>      OnlinePolicySales.Web.Controllers.BaseController..ctor() +79
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +256
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +78
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +92
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'OnlinePolicySales.Web.Controllers.BaseController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +256
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +81
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +270
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +86
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12288259
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Comment: Is your basecontroller abstract class ? How is defined the parameterless constructor ?

Comment: No, its not an abstract class.
`code
 public class BaseController : Controller
    {

        public BaseController()
        {
            MapperHelper.MapModelsToViewModels();
            MapperHelper.MapViewModelsToModels();
        }
...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have something set up to create a database. Note the error in your stacktrace:

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible`

Ensure your database connection string points to a db or server that is accessible in the environment you are trying to run this code in.

I think the `public parameterless constructor` error is a little misleading in this instance.